# PHPUnit testing issues with simple example

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Im new to Unit testing and i have some issues regarding writing test (actually finding simple way to make test for this class). The class itself is pretty simple.

```
public function printUser(string $username = null, string $first_name = null, string $last_name = null)
{
    return $this->someRepository->getPrintListing($username,$first_name,$last_name);
}
```

Comment: You can refer to the official website https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html